# Memory Leak in this short function

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks

Why is this code producing a memory leak?

```
- (void)loadModalInfo
{    
    InformationScreenViewController *infoView = [[InformationScreenViewController alloc] init];
    infoView.url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"NewPatientInfo" withExtension:@"html"]; // LEAKING
   // [infoView setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
    [infoView setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
    [self presentModalViewController:infoView animated:YES];
    [infoView release];
    infoView = nil;
}
```

I'm new using Instruments and I can't figure out why is that code leaking.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the url property on InformationScreenViewController defined as?

Comment: I guess it is an NSURL probably

Comment: Function? Strange. I'd bet it's a method…

Comment: It's a method, sorry for the mistake!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your `InformationScreenViewController.m` in the `dealoc` method release the url.

Comment: Thanks! You're right! I forgot to release the properties in the dealloc method...